# Exporting ggplot graphics into EMS (Enhanced Menu System Configuration) format

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am able to export plots from ggplot2 into .png and .jpeg (or even as standalone plots in .xlsx), but I need to (for various institutional reasons) export plots into EMS (Enhanced Menu System Configuration) format. This is specific to PC tools, and I'm not finding detailed documentation on this format other than generic descriptions. Could anyone advise on whether it is possible to export graphs into EMS, or if there are work-arounds (i.e., converters to EMS, or a file format that supports modifications into EMS format)? I am at a complete loss - not including a reprex as this is a more general question rather than one dealing with specific lines of code.

Thanks to anyone in advance for your help.